# list array function

Tags: php, arrays, list

```
array { 
[0]=> array { [0]=>  "1" [1]=>  "7" [2]=>  "5" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[1]=> array { [0]=>  "2" [1]=>  "3" [2]=>  "7" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[2]=> array { [0]=>  "3" [1]=>  "5" [2]=>  "10" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[3]=> array { [0]=>  "4" [1]=>  "11" [2]=>  "4" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[4]=> array { [0]=>  "5" [1]=>  "12" [2]=>  "9" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[5]=> array { [0]=>  "6" [1]=>  "6" [2]=>  "12" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[6]=> array { [0]=>  "7" [1]=>  "8" [2]=>  "6" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[7]=> array { [0]=>  "8" [1]=>  "0" [2]=>  "14" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[8]=> array { [0]=>  "9" [1]=>  "25" [2]=>  "8" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
[9]=> array { [0]=>  "10" [1]=>  "30" [2]=>  "7" [3]=>  "0" [4]=>  "0" } 
}
```

i would like to ask how can i use `list()` function to list out

```
array{7,3,5,11,12,6,8,0,25,30}
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$yourarray = array();

foreach($array as $arr)
{
    $yourarray[] = $arr[1];     
}

print_r($yourarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

`list()` doesn't work that way, it assigns a one-dimensional array of size `n` to `n` variables. The way this data is structured, the only way I can see to extract that data is a `foreach`, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The "modern" / functional way to isolate a single "column" of data from a two multidimensional array is to call `array_column()` and write the desired column's key as the second parameter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sU41o))

```
$array = [
    ["1", "7", "5", "0", "0"],
    ["2", "3", "7", "0", "0"],
    ["3", "5", "10", "0", "0"],
    ["4", "11", "4", "0", "0"],
    ["5", "12", "9", "0", "0"],
    ["6", "6", "12", "0", "0"],
    ["7", "8", "6", "0", "0"],
    ["8", "0", "14", "0", "0"],
    ["9", "25", "8", "0", "0"],
    ["10", "30", "7", "0", "0"],
];
var_export(array_column($array, 1));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '7',
  1 => '3',
  2 => '5',
  3 => '11',
  4 => '12',
  5 => '6',
  6 => '8',
  7 => '0',
  8 => '25',
  9 => '30',
)
```